# Cannot save ArcGIS Experience Builder project - 'Saving Error'

Tags: arcgis-online, save, arcgis-experience-builder

When I hit 'Save' or 'Save as' on my web app, I get a notification saying 'Saving Error' with no further detail provided. I am able to save other projects with no issue. Similarly if I attempt to preview or publish my work, I am warned that my unsaved work will be lost.

Could anyone advise me what the issue could be? Could it be that I've inadvertently moved or removed the data sources? (if so, how is the project able to display the map at all?)

*Edit*
When I go to "Change share settings" the page opens with the error message "The item you requested cannot be found. The item may have been deleted or you may have entered an incorrect URL."

I have also opened F12 and found this error message in the HTML console: "Access to fetch at 'https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/users/[...]' from origin 'https://experience.arcgis.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

Comment: Not exactly your issue, but possibly related: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000027032. https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000023192. https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000013067

Comment: Thankyou - I have cleared browser cache, but the problem persists. And I don't think this is permissions problem. However, I have done some more investigating and edited my post with further information which might help.

Comment: Perhaps check your CORS settings: https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/administer/configure-security.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_8C832103A9D2442BAC52E914E16AACC2. https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/cors/

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well. I resolved it by signing in. Unfortunately, I don't know if there is a way to save all the work you did while not signed in. I was just experimenting, so I started over once I was signed in.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using experience builder in Portal 10.8.1 Enterprise. I am only able to save projects if the map itself is a public map. This isn't a solution but it may help in the short term.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).